# Update multiple SharePoint list item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

Please I some here...I want to update multiple SharePoint list item using JSOM. First I am retrieving the items using rest api and binding them to an HTML table with checkboxes. The checkboxes have the list item id which I want to use to update the list item...find below my code

```
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SiteAssets/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    getMyTasks();
   approve();
});
function getMyTasks()
{
"use strict";
    var listTitle="hardware%20requisition";
     var row = "";  
     var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items";  
     $.ajax  
     ({  
         url: url,  
         type: "GET",  
         headers:  
         {  
             "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
             "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
         },  
         success: function(data)   
         {  
             var result = data.d.results;  
             $.each(result, function(key, item)  
             {  
                 var l = item.Title;  
                 row = row + '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value=' + item.Id + '>' + item.Id + '</input></td><td>' + item.Title + '</td><td>' + item.L1_x0020_Approver_x0020_Status + '</td><td>' + item.Memory +  '</td></tr>';  
             })  

             $("#GetItems>tbody").html(row);  
             $("#GetItems").show();  
         },  
         error: function(data)   
         {  
             alert("Failed to get list items.");  
         }  
     });  

    }


  function approve(){


    $("#Approve").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchIDs = $("#GetItems input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
    }).get(); 
    alert(searchIDs);


    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("hardware%20requisition");

for(var i = 1; i<= searchIDs.length; i++){    
    var oListItem = oList.getItemById(i);  
    oListItem.set_item('L1_x0020_Approver_x0020_Status', 'Approved!');  
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
}

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));



function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Items Updated');
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

}
    });


  }
</script>
<html>
    <body>
<h2>Get all List Items</h2>  
<button type="button" onclick="GetListItems()">Get Items</button>  
<button type="button" id="Approve">Approve</button>
    <table id="GetItems" style="display:none">  
        <thead>  
            <tr>  
                <td>Id</td>  
                <td>Title</td>  
                <td>Description</td>  
                <td>Quantity</td>  
                <td>Price</td>  
                <td>City</td>  
            </tr>  
        </thead>  
        <tbody>  

        </tbody>  
        </table>  
        </body>
        </html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SiteAssets/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   getMyTasks();
   approve();
});
function getMyTasks(){
    var listTitle="hardware%20requisition";
    var row = "";  
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items";  
    $.ajax({  
        url: url,  
        type: "GET",  
        headers:  
        {  
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        },  
        success: function(data){  
            var result = data.d.results;  
            $.each(result, function(key, item)  
            {  
                var l = item.Title;  
                row = row + '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value=' + item.Id + '>' + item.Id + '</input></td><td>' + item.Title + '</td><td>' + item.L1_x0020_Approver_x0020_Status + '</td><td>' + item.Memory +  '</td></tr>';  
            })  
            $("#GetItems>tbody").html(row);  
            $("#GetItems").show();  
        },  
        error: function(data){  
            alert("Failed to get list items.");  
        }  
    });
}
function approve(){
    $("#Approve").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var searchIDs = $("#GetItems input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
          return $(this).val();
        }).get(); 
        var itemArray = [];
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("hardware requisition");

        for(var i = 0; i< searchIDs.length; i++){    
            var oListItem = oList.getItemById(searchIDs[i]);  
            oListItem.set_item('L1_x0020_Approver_x0020_Status', 'Approved!');  
            oListItem.update();
            itemArray[i] = oListItem;
            clientContext.load(itemArray[i]);
        }
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);       
    });
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Items Updated');
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Get all List Items</h2>  
<button type="button" onclick="GetListItems()">Get Items</button>  
<button type="button" id="Approve">Approve</button>
<table id="GetItems" style="display:none">  
<thead>  
    <tr>  
        <td>Id</td>  
        <td>Title</td>  
        <td>L1 Approver Status</td>     
        <td>Price</td>  
    </tr>  
</thead>  
<tbody> 
</tbody>  
</table>  
</body>
</html>
```